# How to merge this two dataframes this way

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to merge this two dataframes :

```
library(dplyr)
table1 <- data.frame(
  siren = "A",
  siret = "X",
  var1 = 0
)
table2 <- data.frame(
  siren = c("A","A"),
  siret = c("X","Y")
)
```

Expected result :

```
result <- data.frame(
  siren = c("A","A",
  siret = c("X","Y"),
  var1 = c(0,NA)
)
```

Maybe it could be done with a `left_join` in dplyr ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `left_join(table2, table1)`

Comment: Yes I tried `table3 <- table1 %>%  left_join(table2,by = c("siren"))` but it's not the result expected

Comment: Try the code above, it is giving me the expected though

Comment: ok it works without a join by variable ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `left_join` on `table2`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(table2, table1)
```

`by` is not really needed here as it will pick it from the matching names

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
full_join(table1, table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost :) Try a right_join.

```
    right_answer <- right_join(table1, table2)
```

EDIT: As above commenter said, a full_join is a better habit to get into using, though a right_join will get the job done here.